# Hide all open forms including DialogForms

Tags: vb.net, dialog, hide, minimize, notifyicon

How can I `hide` all open forms, including all open `dialog forms` to `NotifyIcon`?

I currently hide the main form using

```
        Me.Hide()
        NotifyIcon.Visible = True
        NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(1, "WinVault", "You've been lockout due to innactivity", ToolTipIcon.Info)
```

And get the form back to show

```
Private Sub NotifyIcon_MouseDoubleClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles NotifyIcon.MouseDoubleClick
    Me.Show()
End Sub
```

I want all open forms including those dialog forms to `minimize` in `NotifyIcon`

Showing dialog forms using `Form.ShowDialog`

Comment: You cannot hide a dialog.  Doing so will automatically close it.  Which in effect will hide it as well :)

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. I tried it as well. Just looking for some suggestions to circumvent it.

Comment: Well, perhaps there is a way to find out if there are any open dialog forms. @HansPassant